# Combine 2 objects and maintain order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of params captured from the router and looking to add 1x additional param to it.

Able to add it fine but looking for a way to maintain order.

I want this new param to be the first followed by the remaining.

Example.

Existing params coming from router.

```
apple=1&orange=2&banana=3
```

I want to append 1 more param to this and have it as the first param as follows.

```
myNewParam=value&apple=1&orange=2&banana=3
```

The following works in combining it.

2 queries. Is there a way to move my new param to be the first?

Cos I've tried to switch them and same results where my new param ends up being the last.

Also do advice if there is a more elegant manner to do this. Using 2x Object dot methods

here feels bit overkill. Or maybe not. Do advice. Thanks.

Working copy but my param **myNewParam** is always last. I want it to be the first.

```
Object.assign(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(router.location.search)), {'myNewParam':'value'});
// same result
Object.assign({'myNewParam':'value'}, Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(router.location.search)))
```

Comment: Do you use `setState` ?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Not gonna involve state for this.

Comment: @karvai Have you found a solution?  I posted an answer using the spread operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the spread operator for objects, available from ECMAScript 2018.

```js
const originParams= {apple: 1, orange: 2, banana :3};

const addedParams = {myNemParam : "value", ...originParams};
console.log(addedParams);
```

Checkout the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)